# mysql swap entry with next higher value

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have this table

```
id      info
1       7
2       3
3       1
4       15
```

I would like to swap an "info"-entry with the next higher info-entry (if it is not the max-val).
So if I process the table above and chose the entry with id 2 I am expecting the resulting table to be

```
id      info
1       3
2       7
3       1
4       15
```

Any ideas are very welcome :-)

Comment: Assuming anyone will have a similar problem I post my work around to get this done (two queries, no valid mySql):

"SELECT DISTINCT MIN(info) AS info
FROM myTable
WHERE info > x"

-> In PHP i make the result be "xSwap", then the next query could be

"UPDATE myTable 
SET info = CASE info 
    WHEN x THEN xSwap
    WHEN xSwap THEN x
   END
WHERE info IN (x, xSwap)"

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t, t as t2
SET t.id = t2.id, t2.id = t.id
WHERE t.id = 1 AND t2.id = 2
```

Comment: uhm. This is swapping two distinct indices and has nothing to do with my actual question.

Comment: Then put it into a function and at beginning check if next id exists and if 'info' value is higher. If not exits break. If not higer - call function again on next element. 

Btw. I think you messed up with description, you wanna swap next element or previous one? Cause example swap with previous one, and u said u calling entry with id 2 and wanna swap with next element.

Comment: It could work with the function approach I wouldn't be sure how to write it though. Also I can imagine there is some more efficient solution with mySql built in functionality.
I think the question is very clear. The condition to be evaluated must be the "info"-column and to give an id as input to the query is perfectly valid while still have the result depending on the info-column only. I wouldn't know how to improve my description.